# Do you feel any difference in meaning between these?

Tags: vocabulary, verbs, infinitives, clauses

I am wondering if there could be any difference in meaning between these?

A. I can get it from the tap and save you pumping.

B. I can get it from the tap and save you from pumping.

C. I can get it from the tap and save you to pump.

Do you really make a distinguish between A and B? or is there any situation which make you distinguish one over the other? I cannot yet get the explanations.

Many thanks

Comment: Yes... the last one is wrong.

Comment: (C) could be made grammatically correct with the addition of just two words: _I can get it from the tap and save you **from having** to pump_.

Answer (score 1):

All are saying that "I" can get it from the tap to do something, and the something is what differs between each of the statements. For the first statement, "you" are saved pumping. That is, "I" get "you" a discount of some sort on pumping (which somewhat makes sense for gas). The second, or B, says that the action of getting it from the tap makes "you" not have to pump any more. It saves "you" the effort of pumping. The third just makes no sense and is wrong, as [Catija](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/16318/catija) says.

Comment: If I had to guess, this would be about someone on a municipal water system able to just get water out of a faucet by turning it on offering to help someone who has a well with a pump that has to be worked to get water.

Comment: @Catija I think you are correct, I said gas because you don't usually pay for pumped water in the same sense as paying for something you can save (like at a store, not usually with gas, water, and electrical bills).

Comment: I think it means save the exertion or work, not money.

Comment: @Catija I know, I meant if you say it like A ("save you pumping") it makes a little bit of sense if it was saving money, but since that is not what the sentence intends, it is a bad way of saying it.

Comment: The third one means that "I" am going to "get it from the tap" so that "you" can pump, either now or in the future.  It seems so totally wrong because it means almost exactly the opposite of the other two.